# sqoop --connection-param-file can path be hdfs path

Tags: hdfs, oozie, sqoop

I am able to succesfully run sqoop export

sqoop export  --connection-param-file /user/xgr0naru/sqoop.properties --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXx --username xx --password xx --table TZ5CK --export-dir  /data/raw/oltp/cogen/oraclexport/TZ5CK/2015-08-18/ --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-escaped-by '\"' --input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"'

The path /user/xgr0naru/sqoop.properties is local, the hdfs path is not working here

But same sqoop export action I need to include in oozie so the path should be in hdfs path
So how can I use hdfs path for --connection-param-file, also when I use -D oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false it doesnt woks but using --connection-param-file it works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Options file can be hdfs (which makes sense if you're running a scheduled Oozie job).  The trick with oozie is to also specify the file(s) using the `<file>` tag.

For example, from workflow.xml :

```
...
<command>--options-file sqoop_params.txt --connection-param-file sqoop_connect_params.txt --password-file sqoop_pwd.txt --target-dir ${someDir}/input-data/sqoop</command>
<file>sqoop_params.txt</file>
<file>sqoop_connect_params.txt</file>
<file>sqoop_pwd.txt</file>
...
```

Make sure to put the configuration files (sqoop_params.txt, sqoop_connect_params.txt) in your appRoot HDFS directory, which is where Oozie reads them by default.  However, the password file must be in your user root HDFS directory.  Oozie setup can be a pita as I'm finding out.

I've tried specifying the entire hdfs path, but it fails for me on 4.2.0 (perhaps a bug in oozie, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

Please add these lines in workflow.xml.

```
<arg>import</arg>
<arg>--options-file</arg>
<arg>${optionFile}</arg>
<file>${optionFile}</file>
<arg>--connection-param-file</arg>
<arg>${connParamFile}</arg>
<file>${connParamFile}</file>
```

Add these codes in job.properties.

```
optionFile=sqoop_option.txt
connParamFile=sqoop_conn_param.txt
```

Place sqoop_option.txt and sqoop_conn_param.txt in HDFS application root folder.